# Tile Collision In GML

Tags: gml

I am making a game based on the game AZ on the website Y8, and I am having problems with tile collisions.
the player moves basically by giving it speed when up is pressed, then rotating left or right.
direction = image_angle;

```
if(keyForward)
{
    speed = 2;
    
}
else speed = 0;

// rotate
if(keyRotateLeft)
{
    image_angle = image_angle + 5;
}
if(keyRotateRight)
{
    image_angle = image_angle - 5;
}
```

then I said when the player collides with the tile speed = 0. But the player gets stuck and can't move anymore. is there a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be as following:

- Attempt to rotate
- Check if you are now stuck in a wall

  - If you are, undo the rotation.

A more advanced approach would be to attempt pushing the player out of solids while rotating.

Alternatively, you may be able to get away with giving the player a circular mask and not rotating the actual mask (using a user-defined variable instead of `image_angle`).